# Deserialize of an API response and display it in view loop

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a problem with response deserialization. What is the best way to deserialize `data` to projects and display it in view in the simplest way? My IDE doesn't find `map()` method.

**Response:**

```
{
    "totalCount": 2,
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "TestProject1",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "TestProject2",
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

**Typescript:**

```
  private usertoken: string;
  private projects: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cookie : CookieService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usertoken = this.cookie.get('usertoken');
    console.log("asdasdasd1");

    this.http.get("https://localhost:5001/api/abc/cba",
      {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.usertoken)})

      .subscribe(data =>{
        this.projects = data;
    });
```

**Html:**

```html
     <table>
     <tr *ngFor="let project of projects">
        <th scope="row">{{ project.totalCount }}</th>
        <!-- <td>{{ project.projectName }}</td> -->
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is the API call actually getting a response?

Comment: Yes. Validated by postman.

Comment: data in http subscription is all your json. You have to do this.projects = data.items and to get total count you hace to set another variable or you still use this.projects = dat; but in the ng for you use `let project of projects.item` and to get total count use {{projects.totalCount}}

Comment: try to use the spread operator to set your projects data

`this.projects = { ...data }`

Comment: let project of projects.item it was a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nico suggested, you are iterating the wrong object. If you set the data directly in the projects, you have the `projects.Items` and `project.TotalCount`, so you should make the for in the Items which is the array.

```
<tr *ngFor="let project of projects.items">
   <th scope="row">{{ projects.totalCount }}</th>  //Get total Count from the main object
   <td>{{ project.title }}</td>  //Get name from the items interaction
</tr>
```